# Is this expression "whose definition" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3361099/697527) just now

> I am learning  space, whose definition is based on function spaces.

Is this expression "whose definition" idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although it is *extremely* common to use forms of *who* in this way.

" space" isn't a *who*, and so *whose* doesn't really fit for it. A more correct phrasing would be something like

> I am learning  space, *the definition of which* is based on function spaces.
>
> or
>
> I am learning  space, *which has a* definition based on function spaces.

If you were [anthropomorphizing](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anthropomorphize?s=t) " space", use of *whose* could be appropriate, but that's a very specific and very unusual case.

But people (in an American English context) are very lax with this type of rule, and relatively few people bother to get it right or would notice and care about the mismatch. Depending on where you are, the correct construction (like *the definition of which*) can seem overly fussy and formal. The idiomatic version is much more common, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "The idiomatic version is much more common", which one is the idiomatic version, "whose", "which has" or some other expression?

Comment: @whnlp The idiomatic (and more common) situation is people using *whose* in a case like this, even though it isn't strictly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since " space" is a thing, but not a person, I would not use "whose" although I have seen math texts use "whose" in similar constructions. I would recast the sentence as one of:

> - I am learning  space, the definition of which is based on function spaces.
> - I am learning  space, which has a definition based on function spaces.
> - I am learning  space, which is defined based on function spaces.
> - I am learning  space: its definition is based on function spaces